# UITextField with trailing placeholder text

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am making an UITextField input where user can enter an subdomain for their site. What i want to accomplish is, that i can show the whole url in the input but only the subdomain part is editable. Any tips how to accomplish that?

**Update**

The right solutions was to use UILabel in UITextField's rightView and calculating the position in rightViewRectForBounds.

Comment: you can use this method to check suffix url is edit or not.. func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool { }

Answer (score 0):

First, UITextField has a property named AttributePlaceholder, it allows to display different color of placeholder.

And then when `didBeginEditing:`, fill the textfield with url, without the subdomain. Remember the count of characters.

When user editing, called on the method:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;`

Return NO when textfield.text.count <= characters.count